# SM59 configuration to get information from .NET connector 3.0

Tags: c#, abap, sap-dotnet-connector, sap-r3

Sap Consultants: I always get the information from sap r/3(RFC) through sap connector 3.0 (c#) succesfully, Without any configuration in sap R/3.

I would like to know if im doing it wrong because someone told me to do it in the correct way (SM59).

> How to do it with SM59 Configuration?
> Please step by step in detail
> if possible,

Comment: you only need to configure a RFC destination if the SAP system has to call a function in your C# code (rarely needed, but for instance if you build an IDoc Receiver -> SAP ERP calls your code, not the other way round). As long as you only call remote function modules in the SAP system, you don't need any configuration in SM59.

Comment: Post this as an answer, Dirk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you only need to configure a RFC destination if the SAP system has to call a function in your C# code (rarely needed, but for instance if you build an IDoc Receiver -> SAP ERP calls your code, not the other way round). As long as you only call remote function modules in the SAP system, you don't need any configuration in SM59.